# What does "he was equally game to slip into bit parts" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was trying to understand this line – *he was equally game to slip into bit parts*, but couldn't. My best guess is that it's meaning something about universality and flexibility in acting. Could somebody, please, make this line more clear or rephrase it?

> Nothing was too big or too small for Hartman. He stepped up as the
>   main, one-off guest voice in episodes like “Brother From the Same
>   Planet”and “Marge vs. the Monorail”. And **he was equally game to slip
>   into bit parts**, including his turn as the weaselly State Department
>   official Evan Conover in “Bart vs. Australia” and sleazy football
>   expert Smooth Jimmy Apollo in “Lisa the Greek”. In “Burns Verkaufen
>   der Kraftwerk”, Hartman showed up as Homer’s lowlife stock broker and
>   as German plant manager Horst. Many of his performances could have
>   merited a big name guest voice, but Hartman nailed them so completely
>   and consistently that you almost didn’t notice it was him
>
> [source](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs6/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> [be game](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+game)  
>   To be willing to do something.
>   *Sure, I'm game to go to the mall.*
>   *Vince is game to play basketball—why don't you go to the park with him?*
>   (TFD)

I assume you can understand *equally*.

I couldn't quickly find a definition for *slip into*, but I see it as a figurative extension of the following:

> [slip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slip)
>   intransitive verb
>   5 : to get speedily into or out of clothing slipped into his coat

In this case, it roughly means *assume*:

> [assume](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/assume)
>   v. tr.
>   3. a. To take on (an appearance, role, or form, for example); adopt: "The god assumes a human form" (John Ruskin).
>   (TFD)

A [*bit part*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_part) is basically a small role:

> A bit part is a role in which there is direct interaction with the principal actors and no more than five lines of dialogue, often referred to as a five-or-less or under-five in the United States, or under sixes in British television.
>   (Wikipedia)

In other words,

> He was equally willing to assume small roles (as he was willing to assume large ones).

Comment: "slip into a role" is an idiom in english, I am surprised that so many dictionaries don't list it.